# how to get php-rdkafka message in browser i will try in command line its give output but not in browser

Tags: php, apache-kafka

```
   <?php
    $rk = new RdKafka\Consumer();
    $rk->setLogLevel(LOG_DEBUG);
    $rk->addBrokers("10.0.0.246");

    $topic = $rk->newTopic("azgar-topic");
    $topic->consumeStart(0, RD_KAFKA_OFFSET_BEGINNING);

        while (true) {
        $msg = $topic->consume(0, 1000);
        if ($msg->err) {
            echo $msg->errstr(), "\n";
            break;
        } else {
            echo $msg->payload, "\n";
        }
   }
```

i try above code in command line its give me output but in browser output will not come rdcafka class not found error come in error log file